# java Check Datatype ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I've got a question. I get the parameters (Observable o, Object arg). I'm playing with the observer pattern.

So now I can check: *arg.getClass().equals(String.class)* to see if the args contains a String type

So now I want to check if it contains an ArrayList: *arg.getClass().equals(ArrayList.class)*

But how can I check if the ArrayList is an ArrayList < String >

The code works without this if clause but I want to know how this can be done. Maybe someone has an idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. [Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html) means that generic information is not available at runtime. Best you can do is check each individual element of the list using your other check.

Comment: Thank you! Then I will check the elements in the list. :)

Answer (score 0):

i know its not a good answer but...

```
if( a.getClass ().equals ( ArrayList.class ) )
        {
            if (!((ArrayList) a).isEmpty ()&&((ArrayList) a).get (0).getClass ().equals ( String.class ))
            \\ do stuff...
        }
```

Comment: Let me try this out :)